# concat with different column with different conditions

Tags: sql, concatenation

```sql
--Create Table
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumbers
(
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(10),
    MobileNum VARCHAR(100),
    ResidenceNum VARCHAR(100)
)

--Insert Data
INSERT INTO PhoneNumbers VALUES
(1,'Joey','9762575422',NULL),
(2,'Ross', '9987796244','8762575402'),
(3,'Chandler',NULL,'7645764689'),
(4,'Monica','8902567839','7825367901'),
(5,'Rachel',NULL,'7845637289'),
(6,'Pheobe','9872435789','9838653469'),
(7,'Gunther',NULL,NULL),
(8,'Mike',NULL,'9700103678')

--Verify Data
Select * from PhoneNumbers
```

I want to  Generate a new column called `Nums` (Number to call).
The conditions to generate the new column (Nums) are:

1. If the MobileNum is not null then take the value from the MobileNum and append ‘MobileNum’ to the data.
2. If the MobileNum is null then take the value from the ResidenceNum and append ‘ResidenceNum’ to the data.
3. If both MobileNum and ResidenceNum are NOT NULL then take the value from the MobileNum and append ‘MobileNum’ to the data.
4. If both EmpMobileNumber and ResidenceNum are NULL then we should get NULL as output.

Comment: what have you done so far? what are you struggeling with? Hint: You are looking for the CASE-statement

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected outcome as tables and show also what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hint: `coalesce`.

Comment: Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: Alternative Hint: CASE statement

Comment: You simply need COALESCE(MobileNum, ResidenceNum)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the CASE-expression

```
CASE
WHEN <something> THEN <something>
WHEN <something_else> THEN <something_else>
ELSE <if_nothing_fits>
END
```

Think about the correct order of the sections because they are being resolved from top to bottom. If something further up is true, then the other sections are not beeing resolved.

Comment: Of course. I changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `COALESCE` use case and there will be no better option.

```
SELECT COALESCE(MobileNum, ResidenceNum) FROM PhoneNumbers;
```

If you really want to prevent this and create a more complex query, you could write a `CASE WHEN` construct.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN MobileNum IS NULL 
THEN ResidenceNum
ELSE MobileNum END
FROM PhoneNumbers
```

I guess the point why you are asking this is that you didn't realize that `NULL` is the default value when a condition is not met. Your question makes the impression you need to add further cases to handle this. This is not required. Whenever both values are `NULL`, the result set of these queries will show them as `NULL`, too.